# No node found for selector in headless true mode of puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless, headless-browser

My enviroment:

- Puppeteer version: 1.20.0
- Platform / OS version: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
- Node.js version: 8.10.0
- Chrome/78.0.3882.0

This error content was printed in terminal:

```
(node:18157) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: No node found for selector: #identifierNext
    at assert (/home/hoangdd3/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:279:11)
    at DOMWorld.click (/home/hoangdd3/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/DOMWorld.js:366:5)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
  -- ASYNC --
    at Frame.<anonymous> (/home/hoangdd3/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:111:15)
    at Page.click (/home/hoangdd3/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Page.js:1037:29)
    at puppeteer.launch.then (/home/hoangdd3/pupperteer/example.js:15:16)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
(node:18157) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:18157) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

This my code:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

puppeteer.launch({
    headless: true
}).then(async browser => {
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setViewport({width: 1920, height: 1080});
    await page.goto('https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/identifier?flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=ServiceLogin',  {"waitUntil" : "networkidle0"});

    await page.waitFor(2000);

    await page.click('input[type=email]');
    await page.keyboard.sendCharacter('phamvancuong4584sg@gmail.com');
    await page.click('#identifierNext');

    await page.waitFor(2000);

    await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('#password > div > div > div > input').click());
    await page.keyboard.sendCharacter('test');
    await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('#passwordNext').click());

    await page.screenshot({path: 'example.png'});

    await browser.close();
});
```

Comment: I have the same issue as you. Please advise if you've solved it. I believe there must be some sort of obfuscation to prevent clicking this button.

Comment: @user2481095: please refer below answer of domlas. i do same that and success.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the problem you are facing refers to selectors, they simply do not exist :). html served in `headless: true` is different to the one on `headless: false`

Your snippet works correctly when used on `headless: false`

There is code which will work in `headless: true`

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: true,
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto('https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/identifier?flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=ServiceLogin',  {"waitUntil" : "networkidle0"});
    await page.waitFor(2000);

    await page.click('#Email');
    await page.keyboard.sendCharacter('phamvancuong4584sg@gmail.com');

    await page.click('#next');

    await page.waitFor(2000);

    await page.click('#Passwd');

    await page.keyboard.sendCharacter('test');
    await page.click('#signIn');

    await page.screenshot({path: 'example.png'});

    await browser.close();
})();
```

On screen `example.png` you can see info with incorrect password (test).

Comment: For `headless: true` how do you determine the selector (ie `page.click('#next')`?

Comment: @RizaKhan at given time i did it in some hacky way using docker and connecting to chrome instance via active web socket.
There's ofc faster way to get DOM for headless google page. Take a look at:
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome

Comment: `await page.waitFor(2000);` is a poor solution -- this is a race condition that might incorrectly stop blocking before the selector is visible, or blocks longer than necessary. `waitForSelector` (or the more general `waitForFunction`) is the preferred approach for a tightly bound loop on visibility of an element.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like in `await page.click('#identifierNext');` theare no element with id=identifierNext

insted of `await page.click('#identifierNext');`

try to use

```
const next = await page.waitForSelector('#identifierNext');
await next.click();
```

Different betwen `click('#identifierNext')` `waitForSelector and click`

waitForSelector - can wait for an element for 30,000s to add an element to DOM

click - if there no element in DOM right now, click will reject Promise